# How should I name a delegate method that returns a "continue" flag?

Tags: swift, delegates

In my Swift code, I have a few methods that look like this:

```
protocol EditorDelegate {
  // ...
  func didStartSearch(query: String) -> Bool
}

class Editor: UIViewController {
  func search(sender: AnyObject) {
    let wasHandled = self.delegate?.didStartSearch(query) ?? false
    if !wasHandled {
       // do default searching behavior
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but it's not self-documenting. The `didStartSearch` method doesn't really communicate that it's returning a flag indicating whether the default behavior should be skipped.

What are some good options for handling this?

Comment: You can explain what `didStartSearch` returns in your documentation

Comment: @CodeDifferent Yes, of course, but I'm looking for something self-documenting / self-explantory

Comment: Method name alone can only do so much. Look at all the function in the C libraries, there's always a section in the `man` page that explain what they return

Comment: names are hard and I commend you for seeking out better names that self-describe.  The best person at naming things that I know of is Martin Fowler. http://martinfowler.com/tags/API%20design.html Does anyone know one that is better?

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow because naming questions are primarily opinion-based: answers can only be based on opinion, not fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to think of a better way to name the delegate function, below is what I came up with that makes the most sense to me. Enums are very powerful in swift, using them can make code more understandable at a glance. Also I like to think of things in terms of different states, which can be clearly defined with enums.

```
enum SearchStatus {
    case Ready
    case Processing
    case Complete(result: String)
}

protocol EditorDelegate: class {
    func statusForSearch(with query: String) -> SearchStatus
}

class Editor: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: EditorDelegate?

    func search(sender: AnyObject) {
        let query = "some input.."
        guard let status = delegate?.statusForSearch(with: query) else {
            // delegate not set
            return
        }

        switch status {
        case .Ready:
            // actually do your search
            break
        case .Processing:
            // search in progress
            break
        case .Complete(let result):
            // do something with result
            print("result = \(result)")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about the relationship between the delegating object and the object being delegated to, and the "message" (in high-level semantics, not just code) that a call to the delegate method is about. That is, does a delegate method call mean, "hey, in case you're interested, this thing happened," or, "this thing happened, what should I do about it?". If the delegate returns a value to the delegating object, you're probably in the second category.

Per [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001803-BCIDAIJE), delegate methods should:

1. Start by identifying the delegating object (e.g. the tableView in `tableView:didSelectRow:` or the window in `windowWillClose:`). This is important because delegation can be a many-to-one relationship — if you have a `delegate` property (or `setDelegate` method) on one class, there's nothing preventing one object from being the delegate of many others, and indeed that can be a useful pattern for whoever adopts your delegate protocol.
2. If the method asks something of the delegate, either name the thing being asked (e.g. `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), or for Boolean conditions, describe the consequence of a positive value — this usually involves language like "should" (e.g. `windowShouldClose`, `tableView:shouldSelectRowAtIndexPath:`).

In your case, it's not entirely clear what "should" happen as a result of the delegate returning `true` or `false`, but here's a guess:

```
protocol EditorDelegate {
    func editor(_ editor: Editor, shouldShowDefaultResultsForSearch query: String) -> Bool
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of return flags is often considered problematic for many reasons.  See [this link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173086/are-flag-variables-an-absolute-evil) for one of many explanations of the arguments for and against.  Nevertheless, one solution that might help in this case would be to use a `typealias`.

```
typealias useDefaultBehaviour = Bool

protocol EditorDelegate {
    func didStartSearch(query: String) -> useDefaultBehaviour
}
```